# Validating XML with external DTD

Tags: xml, xml-validation, xmlstarlet, dtd

Given below are my note.xml and Note.dtd files. I am validating a XML file with external DTD using XMLStarlet from Cygwin. When I give the command

```
xml val --dtd Note.dtd note.xml
```

I get

> cannot parse DTD file

Can someone help me to rectify this?

**note.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE note SYSTEM "Note.dtd">
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Note.dtd

```
<!ELEMENT note (to,from,heading,body)>
<!ELEMENT  (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT from (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT heading (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT body (#PCDATA)>
```

[image: Command from Cygwin]

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
<!ELEMENT (#PCDATA)>
```

to

```
<!ELEMENT to (#PCDATA)>
```

and your XML will be valid against your DTD